# Microsoft signed driver appears as publisher not verfied

Tags: drivers, code-signing

Task at hand:  Microsoft sign drivers on Win 7.

I microsoft signed my driver package 3 times every time thinking I might have missed a step or something.  However, I cannot seem to get rid of the Windows Security error message "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software'.  This is not the first time I have signed the driver packages.  I was successfully able to sign other driver packages a few months ago.  However, with this driver package I keep getting Windows security dialog box.  Here's the procedure I follow -

1. Create a new cat file using INF2CAT tool.
2. Self sign the driver using a Versign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5.cer.
3. Run the microsoft tests on DTM Servers and clients with the devices that use this driver.
4. Create WLK submission package.
5. Self sign the cab file.
6. Submit the package for certification.

The catalog file that comes back after successfully passing tests says Name of signer "Microsoft Windows Hardware Comptibility Publisher".   When I check the validity of signature using SignTool, it says the signature is vaild.  However, when I try to install the driver with new signed catalog file the windows complain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't you forgotten to include the cross-certificate? Common mistake ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How do I do that?

Comment: Hmm, you said you did signing before? There's a parameter in signtool that lets you specify the cross-certificate. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487315.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, Eugene.
Yes.  I did sign two other driver packages before.  One of them was modified version of WinUSB driver.  I am using the same certificate I used when I signed those two driver packages a few months ago.  It costs $250 per signing from Microsoft.  I would think that Microsoft would complain about it during certification if the certificate is wrong.  I use the following command to self sign the CAT file.  I don't have to specify the ceritificate name as  there's only one certificate in the directory -

Signtool sign /v /a /n CompanyName /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll  OurCatalogFile.cat

Below is the result from running Verify command on the Microsoft signed OutCatalogFile.cat

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\x64>signtool verify /v "C:\User
s\logotest\Documents\serialdriversigning\OurCatalogFile.cat"

Verifying: C:\Users\logotest\Documents\serialdriversigning\OurCatalogFile.cat"
Hash of file (sha1): BDDF39B1DD95881B462164129758A7FFD54F47D9

Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Microsoft Root Certificate Authority
    Issued by: Microsoft Root Certificate Authority
    Expires:   Sun May 09 18:28:13 2021
    SHA1 hash: CDD4EEAE6000AC7F40C3802C171E30148030C072

```
    Issued to: Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility PCA
    Issued by: Microsoft Root Certificate Authority
    Expires:   Thu Jun 04 16:15:46 2020
    SHA1 hash: 8D42419D8B21E5CF9C3204D0060B19312B96EB78

        Issued to: Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher
        Issued by: Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility PCA
        Expires:   Wed Sep 18 18:20:55 2013
        SHA1 hash: D94345C032D23404231DD3902F22AB1C2100341E
```

The signature is timestamped: Tue Nov 06 11:26:48 2012
Timestamp Verified by:
    Issued to: Microsoft Root Authority
    Issued by: Microsoft Root Authority
    Expires:   Thu Dec 31 02:00:00 2020
    SHA1 hash: A43489159A520F0D93D032CCAF37E7FE20A8B419

```
    Issued to: Microsoft Timestamping PCA
    Issued by: Microsoft Root Authority
    Expires:   Sun Sep 15 02:00:00 2019
    SHA1 hash: 3EA99A60058275E0ED83B892A909449F8C33B245

        Issued to: Microsoft Time-Stamp Service
        Issued by: Microsoft Timestamping PCA
        Expires:   Tue Apr 09 16:53:56 2013
        SHA1 hash: 1895C2C907E0D7E5C0292B92C6EA8D0E236F525E
```

Successfully verified: C:\Users\logotest\Documents\serialdriversigning\OurCatalogFile.cat"

Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0

Thank you!

### Answer

One of the files in my package was getting modified when I made the package.  I replaced it with the one I used during signing the drivers and I got no error message.  I found the following document useful - [Digital Signatures For Windows® Drivers from Scott M. Johnson Program Manager Windows Hardware Quality Labs Microsoft Corporation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/c/afcf8195-0eda-4190-a46d-aa60b45e0740/driver2.ppt&ei=inyhUI3WOcKB0AHmkoDYBQ&usg=AFQjCNFjGpsX-v5IC5S1A2f3Qdn9aMEP_A&sig2=XVnDgZYqW0ma068L95mqwg)